# CFRetain() NULL error using MFMailComposeVIewController from Xamarin Forms on simulator

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm having a problem sending an email using Xamarin IOS code called from a Xamarin Forms app.

I'm getting the error

> MailCompositionService quit unexpectedly

and looking at the crash report the root cause seems to be

> *** CFRetain() called with NULL ***

This is to do with lower level object cleanup as I understand.

Here's my simplified code that reproduces the issue:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sends the email.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="attachment">Attachment.</param>
private void SendEmail()
{
    if (!MessageUI.MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
        return;

    var mailController = new MessageUI.MFMailComposeViewController();
    mailController.SetToRecipients (new string[]{"john@doe.com"});
    mailController.SetSubject ("mail test");
    mailController.SetMessageBody ("this is a test", false);

    mailController.Finished += (object s, MessageUI.MFComposeResultEventArgs args) => {
        args.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
    };
    UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
}
```

This is called from the main GUI thread.

I'm currently running on the simulator (iOS9) as my Apple Developer account is still being processed, so it could be a simulator bug or limitation although nobody else seems to have recorded it.  Can anybody confirm that this is a simulator issue or indeed that the above code for presenting the view controller is correct?